# Form validation error UI notification

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, validation, asp.net-mvc-5

I think I miss something in my understanding.

```
<div class="form-group">
     @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @class = "form-control" })   
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FirstName, null)
</div>
```

I have Form field and I'd like to perform server validation (so I retrieve the same page if model isn't valid and MVC framework let's me imply on fields that are not valid) I see in bootstrap that I can use the "has-error"  to mark the field if there was an error.

How do I set the div class in case of an error??
to do something like (pseudo code)

```
<div class="form-group @Model.IsValid=false : "has-error" ">
```

how do I tell the razor to set the field with the right error marking so bootstrap will show it as an error field?

Answer (score 0):

This happens in controller,

assuming your current view is Index, which is called like

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  return View("Index", new MyModel());
}
```

and lets say you have an action, which receives the serialized form as model, then you click on submit.

```
public ActionResult SaveInput(MyModel model)
{
  if(!ModelState.IsValid)
    return View("Index", model);
}
```

your model's property must be decorated with some ValidationAttribute

```
[MyValidationAttribute]
public string FirstName {get; set;}
```

That's it, if the validation on some properties failed, the validation field is filled automagically :)

Comment: thanks, I did decorate my property with the [Required] attribute. moreover, I added some error message and I actually see it...but the cool thing of bootstrap with red box I don't get

Comment: @user1025852 and what about the other things I've written here?

Comment: sorry, this was already implemented naturally - if model is not valid I return it - in short it is similar to the flow you presented...I think something is wrong maybe in client side? cause if I decorate with [Required(ErrorMessage = "***")] I see it if field is empty and submit was pressed..

Comment: @user1025852 try calling @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FirstName) without second argument.

Comment: @user1025852 are you sure that you didn't overwrite the corresponding css styles?

Comment: what do you mean by overriding? that my style.css \ site.css \ bootstrap.css are competing with each other? The only "form-control" refreence exist in bootstrap css (just checked..)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48415/discussion-between-user1025852-and-vlad-l)